# Solidity code not giving desired output when input given through Flutter developed application

Tags: flutter, solidity, web3dart

So I am making a web3 application for my final year project in civil engineering degree

I initialized my http clients

```
 Client? httpClient;
  Web3Client? ethClient;
  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    httpClient = Client();
    ethClient = Web3Client(infura_url, httpClient!);
  }
```

inputted all my functions into android studio

```
Future<DeployedContract> loadContract ()async{
  print('loading contract');
  String abi = await rootBundle.loadString('Assets/abi.json');
  String ContractAddress = contractAddress;
  final contract = DeployedContract(ContractAbi.fromJson(abi, 'Login'), EthereumAddress.fromHex(ContractAddress));
  return contract;
}
```

```
Future<String> Login(Web3Client ethClient, String _username, String _password)async{
  DeployedContract contract = await loadContract();
  print('contract loaded');
  final response = await ethClient.call(contract: contract, function: contract.function('login'), params: [_username,_password],);
  print(response);
  return response[0] as String;
}
```

My flutter UI code which takes values from textfield and sends it to the contract is stated below

```
 onPressed: () {
              String Utext = UserText.text;
              String Upass = PassText.text;
              print('a$Utext,b$Upass');
              Login(ethClient!, Utext, Upass).then((String isLoggedin){
                print(isLoggedin);
                if(isLoggedin == 'yes'){
                  Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Client_init(),));
                };
              });
            },
```

The relevant part of my solidity code is also stated below

```
function login(string memory _username, string memory _password) public view returns (string memory) {
        User memory user = users[msg.sender];
        string memory isLoggedin;
        if(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(user.username)) == keccak256(abi.encodePacked(_username)) && 
            keccak256(abi.encodePacked(user.password)) == keccak256(abi.encodePacked(_password))){
            isLoggedin = "yes";
        }
        else{
            isLoggedin = "no";
        }
        return isLoggedin;
    }
```

Now whenever I enter the right value into my textfield into the flutter app and press login, I get the answer [no], even though I should get [yes], this means that my app is able to reach this contract and decode it, so there is nothing wrong with my abi or my ethClient initialization, neither there is something wrong with the way I handle this async function right? then why do I still get [no] as an answer when I should get yes.

Plus on a side not, my register function throws an error of 32000 invalid sender, eventhough I do that transaction with my personal key, can anyone tell me for what reasons do I get invalid sender errors?

Please help a sleep deprived student out :,)

I wanted to input a name and password in my flutter application and for the app to verify it from smart contract and give me an output of [yes]

Comment: Sorry this is slightly off topic of your question but I think you may want to know this - to have a password stored on a contract means that everyone can see it since it has to be added to the contract from an initial transaction (deployment or individual to add user/set password or whatever you have done to set this). Therefore by looking at your contracts transaction list you can see everyones usernames and passwords

Comment: In response to your comment are you storing the username/password as keccak256(abi.encodePacked(x))? - you may want to include this method in your question too since its most likely applicable

Comment: @mattsharp thank you for telling me about the password thingy, I'll store the passwords in the frontend instead of the smart contract. As for your 2nd comment, we're storing the user name and passwords as strings in both the smart contract and the flutter frontend. In the flutter keccak256(abi.encodePacked(x))? is only used in the if statements, I hope that answers your question. Im new to coding so I might have not understood your terminologies and may have misunderstood your question

Comment: yes that answers my question which means the code looks fine and should work if the strings are the same. Maybe you are not trimming the string or something (spaces) or maybe different cases ie. UserA and usera? It could also be that maybe your use isn't getting returned, you can check this by putting a line underneath the "User memory user = users[msg.sender];" line - "require(user.username.length > 0)" (since there is no such thing as null, maybe the user youre bringing back is empty and you're comparing to empty).

Comment: You have a side note of "my register function throws an error of 32000 invalid sender" - I see nowhere where you set this in the code you have provided above. Don't post your private key here obviously but include where this is set. This most likely relates to your other question where msg.sender needs to be set. You dont have to use a private key to set this in a "view" request, you can add the address you want to send from as the fromAddress in the call to the contract. This also means you can spoof fyi so a view function for login is not secure